# Why Address Book Missing Styles and the rest of the Body?

Tags: magento2, customer, styles

When logged into a customer account, if you click on "Address Book" in the sidebar, it takes you to a page that is in just the form without the rest of the sites body, and without any styling. Just a form with no way to submit it without any styles.

Not sure what files to even begin to troubleshoot in since we don't really deal with Magento 2.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any XML file that overrides the default address book page?